# Where is the reference for the reStructuredText roles needed for using Sphinx and Sphinx's autodoc like Javadoc?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

I would like to use reStructuredText, Sphinx, and Sphinx autodoc for Python code in the same way one uses Javadoc for Java code, that is, for specifying parameters and return values, but also for linking to other classes, methods, etc.

I am finding it very hard to find a reference for learning how to do this. The [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#field-lists) mentions `:param` and `:return:` in passing, as mere examples of field lists. I cannot find a proper reference for these roles (and similar ones I imagine exist, such as one for "see also") anywhere.

More importantly, I find it unclear how to create links for other classes and methods, especially if those are in other packages.

Is this the main way Python developers extract documentation from source code? If so, I would expect some clear documentation and reference for this purpose somewhere.

**Update**: please note that I don't mean [the autodoc reference](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html#autodoc). This page explains how to import docstrings into arbitrary Sphinx documents. It does *not* explain which roles can be used in docstrings to document parameters, return values, types, or to link to other methods and classes. For instance, a search on this page for `:param` does not find anything.

Comment: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/quickstart.html#autodoc

Comment: @StevePiercy, that sounds reasonable but does not really answer the question. Please see update at the end of question.

Comment: `:param:`, `:return:` etc: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists

Comment: Linking to classes etc: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects

Comment: Also take a look at the Napoleon extension, which supports docstring styles that many people find more legible: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html

Comment: @mzjn, cool, please write an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReST fields such as `param` and `return` that can be used in docstrings are described under "Info field lists" in the "Python domain" section: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists.

The roles that are available for creating cross-references to documented Python objects are described here: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects.

You should also take a look at the Napoleon extension, which supports docstring styles that many people find more legible: https://sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html.